# Google Auth not working on Heroku for a flask/react app

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, google-authentication

I am trying to implement GoogleAuth on my app, and although it works on localhost, the GoogleAuth does not work on Heroku. When I click on Login with Google on the signup page it says this, `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch... If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies. origin: https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com` and if I do it from the login it says this `Error 401: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found.` None of this is a problem on localhost but I ran out of ideas on what to do to fix this. I have added the ID and the secret key on the config vars on heroku, and I added `https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com` on the JavaScript Origins and the redirect URIs, but it just does not work, the `OAuth Consent Screen` is also in Production so I just cannot figure out what's wrong. The Google Info is also on a .env. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Repo: **https://github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Astrogram**
Live: **https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com**

There is an issue that when you switch from login-signup sometimes the button seems to be disabled but refreshing the page enables it again, but that's not really the main concern, the main problem is GoogleAuth not working on Heroku despite the fact that it does work on localhost. This is a Flask/PostrgreSQL/SQLAlchemy/React/Redux app.

Comment: have you re-downloaded the credentials file? After adding stuff on the JavaScript Origins and the redirect URIs you need to download the updated credentials...

Comment: So I am very new to using GoogleAuth(first time), I downloaded the JSON file... but am I supposed to add it somewhere? The ClientID remains the same. But am I supposed to do something with this?

Comment: {"web":{"client_id":"60xx","project_id":"astrogram-jeff","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xx_-","redirect_uris":["https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com","https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com/google/authorized","https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com/oauth2/redirect"],"javascript_origins":["https://astrogram-jeff.herokuapp.com","https://localhost:3000"]}}

Comment: the credentials object should have a `redirect_uris` and `javascript_origins` key/value pair. Go to Cloud Console --> Apis and services --> Credentials and download the correct one from there. It should contain the previously mentioned key/value pairs...

Comment: You might need to create a new one if it doesn't exist. See [this doc](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849)

Comment: just to show how my prod credentials.json looks like: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/kpPKaw9)

Comment: Hey Edo, so I did that and that’s why I sent that message with “web”:{….}, but I guess my question is where exactly would I pass that info in my project. I did download that from Credentials but I’m not sure what to do with that info as in where do I pass it/use it. I know I need a GoogleClientId and a SecretId but that’s pretty much all I know I’m using. Sorry if my message did not make sense.

Comment: can you add some code related to how you create the client? I think the issue might be related to this...

Comment: @EdoAkse hope this is what you were looking for. https://astrogram.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2021-09-04+at+5.43.19+PM.png https://astrogram.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2021-09-04+at+5.45.19+PM.png https://astrogram.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2021-09-04+at+5.49.06+PM.png